# Help with IK Rigging

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

I have IK rigged my model legs but this happens.

[image]

we all know that it suppose to go forward not backwards. Can someone help me . Thanks ^_^

Comment: Could you post a .blend file and/or some more details, it is very hard for us to tell exactly what is going on.

Comment: O.O ok how do i do it? do i need to upload it to mediafire or ect?

Comment: @ViroreMetroid Yes, a file hosting service is required

Answer (score 1):

You need to limit the IK movement for the bones. The parameters are found under the bone tab. Check the *limit* option for the proper axis.

The line signifies where the bone(s) will go to accommodate the IK and will change when you change the degrees. Set it where ever you like.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like you must rotate some bones in Z axes in edit mode... Just play around with rotations od them till you get normal legs. You might need to rotate top leg bones, and than also the bottom ones(yellow)...